# Jquery - How to show alert box on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i am using below code for onclick alert box using jquery, but i need the same alert box as a onload function.

```
   <link href="mdl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #5D9CEC;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4A89DC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:30px 10px;
}
</style
<div class="jquery-script-ads" style="margin:30px auto;">
</div>  <a class="btn" id="btn-2" data-type="confirm" data-fullscreen="false" data-overlayClick="true"> Confirm Dialog </a> </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="mdl.js"></script>

<script>

$('#btn-2').mdl({
  content:"Are You Sure To Delete This Entry?"

});


</script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you want an alert every time the page loads, or do you want the `mdl` function to apply to `btn-2` **after** the page has loaded?

Comment: every time when page loads i need alert box

Comment: Assuming I've understood what you're trying to do, try raising a `click()` event on the button, ie `$('#btn-2').mdl({ /* settings */ }).click()`

Answer (score 0):

Fire the click event on load using `$.fn.trigger`

```
$('#btn-2').mdl({
  content:"Are You Sure To Delete This Entry?"
}).trigger('click')
```

Comment: thank u soo much  its working but and i have small doubt this alert contain yes and no buttons but i  just need  ok button.can you help me plz

Comment: I would look for a different plugin if this one doesn't have the option

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(
   function() {

```
           alert(" content:"Are You Sure To Delete This Entry?");
        }
   );
```

Comment: Rather than just posting [ill-formatted] code, you should do your best to explain it. By the way, the code your provided, isn't even valid JavaScript.